# Blocking specific file extension with htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using this code to send all the request to a single php file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) myfile.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

But now I want to also block **direct access** to myfile.php and other phps. I don't want the php files to open directly via browser, but they must work for includes and such.

How can I do this?

Comment: I think you will get into trouble if you rewrite everything as myfile.php but then deny access to myfile.php. Or am I misunderstanding th question?

Comment: The rewrited urls looks like http://domain.com/stuff/substuff, and stuff/substuff is processed by myfile.php so the php is not open directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this will help:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*).php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.* - [F,L]
```

Several nice examples are here: [Apache wiki: RewriteCond](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteCond)

Comment: But that doesn't work for (lets say) `.php`, `.inc`, `.bak`, `.ext` altogether. Do i need to write line by lines for each extensions?

Comment: All works well. But you need to be sure that RewriteEngine is on, i.e. full version:
`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*).php$ [NC]
 RewriteRule ^.* - [F,L]
</IfModule>`

Answer (score 5):

You can block files with the **Files** directive. To block files ending in .inc, do this:

```
<Files ~ "\.inc$">
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</Files>
```

Comment: But that doesn't work for (lets say) `.php`, `.inc`, `.bak`, `.ext` altogether. Do i need to write line by lines for each extensions?

Comment: To block multiple extensions, you can just use a regex like `<Files ~ "\.(inc|bak|ext)$"> `

Comment: Please note that this one might not work on Apache 2.4+. See https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/upgrading.html