# PHP file doesn't rewrite

Tags: php, file, permissions, fopen

I make a site map, and make it with php file, that generate it from mysql. I change host and now I have problem with writing into file. I can't understand something.
Here is my example:

```
<?php 
$xml = 'bla bla xml'; //... some xml generating code
$fp = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/my_site_map.xml', 'w');


   if($fp)
      echo 'we opened it';
   else
      echo 'we failed';

   $fwrite=fwrite($fp, $xml, strlen($xml));

   if($fwrite==false)
      echo "another fail";

   fclose($fp);

   echo "we done";

?>
```

The question is: my file my_site_map.xml have a permission 664 (rw-rw-r--), and I can't use this script if I open this php page from browser, so, if I try to do this I'll see: "we failed another fail we done"; But if I open this through crontab and see a log file, I can see this: "we opened it we done". I want exactly this but the main problem is that the file isn't have been rewritten. Why? And how can I fix this? Thanks.

My server is nginx not an Apache, didn't thought that this info will valuable

Comment: i think the file permitions should by chmod 777

Comment: or try using file_put_contents

Comment: More often than not you need to chgrp to client and chown to www_serv as well as the chmod 777, though I think 775 would be fine.

Comment: @user2051349 Is it is secure to use 777 permission to sitemap and any other file?

Comment: Just a guess: `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` might already have a trailing slash, so try removing it before your file. ie (`$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 'my_site_map.xml'`)

Comment: @defaultNINJA hmm I thought that when I use crontab the chown is www_data and mm why I must change group to a client? I have a little misunderstanding with these terms.

Comment: When your making file changes via a php page it's the php web server accessing the file. I've had to do this on more than one occasion. Mainly when I was creating excel files via Ajax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I don't have enough rep to comment so this will have to be an answer.

I'm going to take a stab in the dark and say the file is owned by your user or root, not the process that is running the webserver. Nor is the file owned by the group the webserver process is run under.

So either chown/chgrp the file to be owned by the apache(?!) process running, e.g. chown apache file or set the file to have write permissions to everyone, e.g. chmod 666 file

Don't chmod 777 as commented above unless it's an executable file and you want anyone to be able to run it. The 1st solution is a better practice than just giving anyone read access to a file.

Edit: In comment to the comments on the original answer above, if the file isn't an executable then don't give it 7 for any permisions. 6 is read/write and is suitable for a text file you are opening to write to (even 2 is if it comes to that).

Edit 2: Try catching any exceptions that your fopen function runs in a try catch block:

```
try { 
    $fp = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/my_site_map.xml', 'w'); 
} catch (Exception $e) { 
    echo "The error is" . $e->getMessage(); 
}
```

Comment: flinth, from your comment on the other answer, you need the chown www-data <your file> the file then.

Comment: yes I just re-read your answer and understood this), I'll try to do this right now

Comment: what about group of my file? Now group is `root`, I must change it to `www-data` too or leave as `root`?

Comment: You don't need to change this. If you look at the unix permissions you mentioned earlier (664) you can break it down into 3 sections. The 1st 6 is for the owner, the second 6 is for the group and the 4 at the end is for everyone else. So long as either one of the owner or the group have a 6 this will work.

Comment: (ran out of space), provided the owner is the process trying to access the file, or a member of the group assigned to the file.

Comment: hmmm, that's not so good in my case, because it doesn't worked

Comment: stop, I was wrong! It works, but not as I want, it work if I open file that make and xml file from browser, but it didn't if cron run it.

Comment: Well you can test if it worked by either looking in your apache logs for an error from the fopen function (the logs are usually in /var/httpd/log, /var/apache/log or /var/log/httpd depending on your distro). You want to look in the error log for an exception when you run the script. Alternatively you can trap the exception if there is one when you open the file in a try catch block, like this:

try {
$fp = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/my_site_map.xml', 'w');
} catch Exception $e {
echo $e->getMessage();
}

Comment: my server is nginx, but I was wrong, it works read my comment above, how can I make to run it from crontab and mm "close" it from running from the web (may be just from the browser or something)

Comment: Okay, so is that the opposite to what it was before? That is, it works from the browser but not from cron? What user is the cronjob run by?

Comment: I found that cron is running from user `root`, so, I must change owner to root? mm cronjob also runs from `root`

Comment: Well, no really, as root has access to everything. How are you adding the cron job? Do you log in as root and use crontab -e, or do you run crontab -e -u root (maybe with sudo)?

Comment: I just login in as root and use crontab -e

Comment: hmm may be the problem is with php-cli? just a guess

Comment: Okay. Have you added a script interpreter header to the file (shbang).
So for example #!/usr/bin/env php as the very 1st line of the script?
If that is missing then it won't work. The reason for this is because nginx/apache knows how to handle a php file, but the unix shell doesn't, unless you supply it an interpreter to handle it. On the flip side, if you add that line to the top of the script now your webpage will have an ugly line at the top saying what the shbang says, as apache/nginx just interpets it as plaintext. The way around this is to set your cronjob us to use the command with...

Comment: the interpret. So instead of just putting the cronjob as e.g. 
0 0 * * * /my/php/file you would do e.g. 0 0 * * * /usr/bin/env php /my/php/file.
Now your cron job says 'run the php interpreter, and supply it with my php script to run,' in which case you can leave off the shbang

Comment: i use this like `0 0 * * * /usr/bin/php5 /my/php/file` I think this is equal as you said, by the way I have other cronjobs and they work fine

Comment: Yep if that's the path to your php file that's fine. What happens if you run that exact command as root (so not as a cron job). So just run /usr/bin/php5 /my/php/file on your unix shell. Does it run as intended? Do you get any errors?

Comment: Oh and another thing, the $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] variable is set by your webserver, not by when you just run a php script, you should change that to a full path to the file in your script.

Comment: Oh, that's really strange for me, it show me the output from my php script(echo from the end of it), but it doesn't rewrite my file

Comment: Did you refactor this line to not use the $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] variable?
$fp = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/my_site_map.xml', 'w');
   So instead use something like $fp = fopen('/full/path/to/my_site_map.xml', 'w');

Comment: for the full path you mean mm  www.domain.com/my_file.php or /var/.../my_file.php ? Anyhow right now the path is /var/.../my_file.php of course if $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] work from command line

Comment: Yeah! you were right $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] must be changet to the string path :) Oh thank you) I'll try to run it through cron, but i think it work. A little question how can I restrict access from the outside to this file?

Comment: No, not the full path for your web domain, the full path on the actual unix machine. That's what I mean, $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] doesn't work on the command line, it is blank. So the script thinks your file is just /my_site_map.xml, which it isn't.

Comment: It's work from cron and cmd line now:) Thank you:)  A little question how can I restrict access from the outside to this file?

Comment: What do you mean when you say the outside? As in people accessing it via your website or people on the unix machine?
If it's on the unix machine then just make sure other people don't have membership to the group that owns it, or can log in as root or the owner. If it's on the website, then you have to set this up in apache. You can either put it in a new directory and put in your site.vhost file to exclude running files from that directory, or you can give it a particular file extension and set to exclude those

Comment: the second answer in this question shows how to do the file extension blocking: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6501575/blocking-specific-file-extension-with-htaccess

Comment: No worries mate! Glad you got it sorted!

Answer (score 0):

For PHP code here are the links to change it on the fly. You can change it to what ever make your edits then change it back as needed.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.chown.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.chgrp.php

Examples are included on each link with the documentations. Find the permissions that works best for what your doing. There isn't a one size fits all for permissions since it really depends on your end product (web app, page, what ever).